# Intel Rapid Start Technology Incompatible with Whole-Disk Encryption?

Tags: windows, windows-8, encryption, disk-encryption, intel-rapid-start

I have a brand new Dell XPS 15 laptop, and I'm getting the following message popping up from time to time.

[image: User Security Recommendation Message]

Searching around, I see that Windows 8.1 is supposed to have whole disk encryption enabled by default for systems that support it.

The problem is that when I go to Windows 8.1's settings under PC and devices | PC info, I see no mention of disk encryption. The articles I've read suggest this indicates that my system does not support it.

Questions:

1. Why am I getting this message if my system doesn't support whole-disk encryption, and is there a way to determine for sure if this encryption is enabled or not?
2. Does anyone know what terrible things happen if I leave both Intel Rapid Start Technology and whole-disk encryption enabled?
3. Can anyone imagine why Dell is sending out computers, apparently, with invalid configurations.

**Update**

Actually, the [link in the message](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/rst/rst_faq.htm) does contain some helpful information, such as:

> What full disk encryption solutions work best with Intel Rapid Start Technology? 
>   To maintain the benefits of Intel Rapid Start Technology and full disk encryption, we recommend using a hardware-based full disk encryption solution and enabling an ATA security password.
>
> Published guidance for software-based full disk encryption usually involves disabling Windows Standby/Sleep state and using Hibernate or Shut Down instead. Disabling the Sleep state means that Intel Rapid Start Technology may not be used.

But I'm still unclear why I can't confirm disk encryption is enabled.

Comment: Windows 8.1 encryption is only enabled on certain types of devices. Its not enabled for example on Desktop products, if you want encryption on a desktop, Bitlocker should be used. Provide a screenshot of what you do see.  **Unless your using Bitlocker your not using the same encryption solution your reading about.**

Comment: Thanks, but that comment seems at odds with [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/173592/windows-8.1-will-start-encrypting-hard-drives-by-default-everything-you-need-to-know/).

Comment: This is the reason I don't like that website. Bitlocker is NOT `Pervasive Device Encryption` one is handled by the user the other introduces some "wide usage compromises" for example the ability to backup your key to your Microsoft Account. Did your laptop come with Windows 8.1? If it did not then its not enabled, it could be enabled, but its not enabled if you upgraded from Windows 8.0 to Windows 8.1. I still want to see what you see a screenshot works.  You also have to link your local account to your Microsoft Account ( again one of the compromises they made to bring it to the masses ).

Comment: I assume you have verified your using the current version of IRST?

Comment: Again, the laptop is brand new. Came last Friday with Windows 8.1. My Microsoft account is linked and verified.

Comment: I found BitLocker settings (it's disabled), but I haven't found anything about this new encryption setting that is on by default and is causing messages to appear about being incompatible with Intel Rapid Start.

Comment: Brand new is something different to everyone.  It could be a brand new used computer for all I know.  Give us the specific technical specifications.  Speccy is a great tool, lets you link to a generated log, with everything we could need.  I still need a screenshot of the modern ui Settings window to be honest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14655/discussion-between-ramhound-and-jonathan-wood) but give me a few hours I can't do it yet.

Comment: Regarding the modern UI Settings, I need to know which screen you want an image of. I found an article that showed the related settings but that entire section is not visible on my computer.

Comment: Lets start with `PC and Devices`

Comment: Uploaded to the chat you started.

Comment: I just got that message out of the blue on a laptop I've been using for months. Nothing's changed about the system configuration, especially regarding encryption. Shortly before I saw the message, I did plug in an external drive that did *not* have encryption. No idea what to think.

Comment: ...actually, I unplugged and replugged the external drive, and the message popped up again shortly after. Again, no encryption on the drive. Maybe a bug in their detection?